# Displaying Null or Undefined in React and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to display the undefined or null values as `italicize`. If its empty string then output as is. If it has a value then output as is.

The problem right now is that its outputting as [Object Object] for null or undefined.

Codesandbox: [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-forked-7w1d0d?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: "id", hide: true },
  {
    field: "col1",
    headerName: "Column 1",
    width: 150,
    renderCell({ value }) {
      return `${
        value === null || value === undefined ? (
          <div style={{ fontStyle: "italic" }}>null</div>
        ) : (
          String(value)
        )
      }`;
    }
  },
  {
    field: "col2",
    headerName: "Column 2",
    width: 150,
    renderCell({ value }) {
      return `${
        value === null || value === undefined ? (
          <div style={{ fontStyle: "italic" }}>null</div>
        ) : (
          String(value)
        )
      }`;
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're wrapping the return value of `renderCell` in a template literal string. You should remove that and just return the actual React node itself, or the string if it's defined. So try this:

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: "id", hide: true },
  {
    field: "col1",
    headerName: "Column 1",
    width: 150,
    renderCell({ value }) {
      return (
        (value === null || value === undefined) ?
        <div style={{ fontStyle: "italic" }}>null</div> :
        String(value)
      );
    }
  },
  {
    field: "col2",
    headerName: "Column 2",
    width: 150,
    renderCell({ value }) {
      return (
        (value === null || value === undefined) ?
        <div style={{ fontStyle: "italic" }}>HI</div> :
        String(value)
      );
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: Do I also need to do `String(value)` or just `value`?

Comment: @Joseph just `value` should be fine, not much point casting it